# Constructing a mac scheme secure to regular definition but insecure to special case

Tags: provable-security, mac

The mac-forge security game for mac schemes looks like this:

1. $k \leftarrow \operatorname{Gen}(1^n)$;
2. $(m,t) \leftarrow A^{\operatorname{MAC}_k(⋅)}(1^n)$;
3. Let $Q$ denote the set of all queries that $A$ asked to its oracle;
4. The output of the experiment is defined to be $1$ if and only if $\operatorname{Verif}_k(m,t)=1$ and $m \notin Q$.

So, in this experiment the adversary has acces to a $MAC(.)$ oracle. But let's consider another experiment that where the adversary also has acces to a verify oracle, but otherwise the experiment is the exact same. Let's call the experiment mac-forge*.

If we consider a mac scheme that is secure with respect to both these definitions, can we then make a new scheme from it, that is secure for mac-forge, but not mac-forge*?

I suspect something strange should be done to the verify function, but I really don't know what.

**Edit**

If I construct vrfy* like:

```
vrfy*k(m,t) = if tag has correct length, just Mac(m), and if Mac(m) = t
```

, output true, elif if Mac(m) != t output false
if tag is smaller than it should be, and has length i, output the i'th bit of the key

Comment: Hint: Can you somehow have the verify function leak information without impeding correctness?

Comment: SEJPM: I was thinking maybe something regarding also letting the verify do a mac?

Comment: Is there perhaps some (static?) secret the verification function could leak one bit at a time?

Comment: I guess youre hinting towards the key :) but if the adversary has the key what would he use it for? isnt it useless since he doesnt know the inner workings of the oracle functions?

Comment: Ahh, an adversary is always assumed to know everything about the scheme in question besides the things that are dynamically generated and not handed to them, which is usually only the key.

Comment: ahh cool! so if an adversary has a key, then because he know the key then he can run the algorithm "for himself" without using the oracle, and thus obtaining a correct pair (m,t)

Comment: I'll just add an edit wíth my idea

Comment: I don't see how vrfy* meets the mac-forge security game; the attacker can submit as his guess an arbitrary message and a one bit tag; if bit 1 of the key happens to be 1 (probability 0.5), then he wins (and I believe the rules of the game is he wins if his guess is correct with nonneglible probability)

Comment: yeah thats a good point

Comment: But how in the world would I then get a vrfy* that works exactly as it should, but is also breakable?

Comment: @SEJPM could you give some more hints? im really at the end of my wits

Comment: Ok, can you somehow amend the full-sized tag to get the targeted leakage from your previous approach? Can you somehow ensure that you don't get spurious 1s output in situations where you don't want them from there?

Comment: I could do a vrfy that works in the exact same way as the normal one, except if i bits 1 is appended to the tag in a pair (t,m) that would otherwise be accepted, then vrfy would output the i'th bit of the key?

Answer (score 1):

Using your terminology, if a scheme is secure in the `mac-forge` game then it is also secure in the `mac-forge*` game. The formal proof is a bit fussy I can sketch the main idea.

First, without loss of generality, assume that in the `mac-forge*` game the adversary never queries the verification oracle on $(m,t)$ that was a result of a prior MAC query. This is without loss of generality because we already know what the verification oracle will answer (true) on such an input, so there is no need to query.

> **Claim:** If the MAC scheme is secure in `mac-forge` then in the `mac-forge*` game the verification oracle will answer false to all queries.

The proof idea is as follows: Suppose we have an adversary $A$ who breaks security of the `mac-forge*` game. We will use it to construct a new adversary that breaks the security of the `mac-forge` game. Suppose $A$'s $i$th query to the verification oracle is the first one that returns true. Construct a new adversary $A^*_i$ which does the following in the `mac-forge` game:

- run $A$
- whenever $A$ makes a MAC query, make the same MAC query in the `mac-forge` game and relay the result back to $A$
- when $A$ makes verification queries 1 through $i-1$, give the answer `false`  to $A$
- when $A$ makes the the $i$th verification query $(m,t)$, halt with output $(m,t)$.

So $A^*_i$ plays in the `mac-forge` game (it never makes verification oracle queries). If $A$'s $i$th verification query really was the first one that returns true, then:

- $A^*_i$ provides a view for $A$ that is identical to when $A$ plays the `mac-forge*` game (identical until we terminate $A$ early)
- $A^*_i$ halts with a valid forgery.

So $A^*_i$ breaks the `mac-forge` security of the scheme.

This is just a sketch, and it somewhat assumes that it is *always* the $i$th verification query that works. In the real proof, you would choose $i$ uniformly at random and incur a loss in concrete security.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is a homework assignment that tries to have the student come up with [the separation between UF-1 and UF-M as defined in this paper (and proven to be distinct for the non-strong case)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/309) where the availability of a verification oracle was proven to be a stronger definition than only having one verification query at the end.

Comment: OK, I see that the guard condition in the top post is "$m$ never queried to MAC", not "$(m,t)$ never the result of MAC query". Also the construction in that paper does not use a canonical verification algorithm. Seems like a wicked homework assignment.